The assignment of derived infinity category of étale sheaf is an infinity functor?
Consider the ordinary category of schemes $Sch$, for $X\in Sch$, consider the abelian category of étale sheaf with coefficient $\wedge$ as $Mod(X_{ét},\wedge)$, then we can form the derived infinity category of this abelian category $D(X,\wedge)$, either by Lurie's HA section 1.3.5, or by Gaistgory's Weil's conjecture for function fields section 4.
The assignment of derived infinity category of étale sheaf has functoriality in the sense that: for $f: X\rightarrow Y$, there is a morphism of sites $Sch_{Y}^{ét}\rightarrow Sch_{X}^{ét}$ by the base-change formula, which induces an adjunction $f_*$ and $f^*$.
$\textbf{Is there any way to construct an infinity functor Sh$( -,\wedge):Sch^{op}\rightarrow Pr^{L}$ encoding the}$ $\textbf{above assignment?}$
I don't think I can construct this by a combinatorial way of clarifying all the simplices and the coherent conditions using simplicial set model, and I see in many cases, the infinity functor are not constructed directly but induced (for example, by some Kan extension) or when the target is $Cat$, using the coCartesian fiberation. For the assignment of quasi-coherent sheaf on DG affine schemes, there is indeed an infinity functor, by HA, but what about the constructible setting?
I see in HA proposition 1.1.3.20 where there is a right Quillen functor given by the formation of differential graded nerve from the category of $Cat_{dg}$ (equipped with a combinatorial model category as shown in prop 1.1.3.19) to the category of simplicial sets (endowed with the Joy model structure). This seems to provide an infinity functor from the infinity category of dg categories to the infinity category of infinity categories when passing to the infinity categories underling the model categories.
This inspires me since the derived infinity category $D(X,\wedge)$ is exactly the differential graded nerve of dg category $Ch(Mod(X_{ét},\wedge))^{fib}$ (here $^{fib}$ means the full subcategory of fibrant objects, see HA definition 1.3.5.8), so since we already we have an infinity functor from $Cat_{dg}$ to $Cat$, then it remains to construct a functor from $Sch$ to $Cat_{dg}$ by assigning $X$ to $Ch(Mod(X_{ét},\wedge))^{fib}$, however it fails because in $Cat_{dg}$, the composition is strict equality but the composition of pushforward or pullback can only be  natural isomorphisms $(f\circ g)*\cong f^*\circ g^*$.
I believe there must be some references explaining this, I would appreciate it for any ideas or information on this.

references on the infinity-categorical six functor formalism approach do even more than this. One reference doing what you ask is Enhanced six operations and base change theorem for higher Artin stacks by Yifeng Liu and Weizhe Zheng.

@WillSawin Thanks, I shall take a look at it.

I’m not sure what problem you’re talking about. An equality $g^* \circ f^* = (f \circ g)^$ induces an equivalence $g^ \circ f^* \simeq (f \circ g)^*$ by taking the identity morphism.

@TimCampion Yes, but for both pushforward and pullback we don’t have equality but isomorphism, right? So I can't construct a functor from $Sch$ to $Cat_{dg}$ because the composition law in the latter category is strict.

The pushforward of sheaves is given by $f_(F)(V) = F(f^{-1}(V))$ and is strictly functorial: $g_(f_(F))(W) = f_(F)(g^{-1} (W)) = F(g^{-1}(f^{-1}(W))) = F((f \circ g)^{-1}(W)) = (f \circ g)_*(F)(W)$. So derived pushforward is also functorial (note that pushforward preserves injectives, and hence fibrant objects). So derived pusforward is funtorial. Now the left adjoint of the derived pushforward is functorial beause taking adjoints is contravariantly functorial. This is the derived pullback.

@TimCampion Thanks, I think this is very inspiring, and this is definitely true for the topological space, but the morphism between étale sites in this context shall involve base change (pullback), which is only unique up to isomorphism, then $f^{-1}(V)$ is still up to isomorphism well defined (?).

Ah I see . Sorry I missed that you were talking about the etale sites, though you stated it very clearly. Yeah in that case to use the kind of approach I was talking about you’d probably need to know that that the dg nerve is functorial in pseudofunctors (probably true but more work to show)
